# How can we work with generic types and primitives in Java

Tags: java, templates, generics, types, primitive

I have an object that contains an array, but the type of the array will be diffent every time.

I could do something like

```
class MyObject<T>
{
    public T [] data;
}
```

The thing is that this does not work with primitive types (int, double, ...) and it makes me work with Objects (Integer, Double...).

Is there any way of avoiding this?

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware that [autoboxing in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) may do exactly what you're looking for.
See this code example from the link:

```
// List adapter for primitive int array
public static List<Integer> asList(final int[] a) {
    return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
        public Integer get(int i) { return a[i]; }
        // Throws NullPointerException if val == null
        public Integer set(int i, Integer val) {
            Integer oldVal = a[i];
            a[i] = val;
            return oldVal;
        }
        public int size() { return a.length; }
    };
}
```

That `get()` method is returning a plain old data type `int` that is automatically converted into an `Integer`.  Likewise, the `set()` method is taking an `Integer` and assigning an `int` element in the array.

Autoboxing is not an immediately obvious feature but it does handle the automatic object creation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use primitives in generics, like you can in C++ with Templates.

If you want a collection which uses primitives I suggest you look at http://trove.starlight-systems.com/  You can pass this collection type as part of the generic. i.e. instead of passing the primitive type, pass the collection type.

```
MyObject<List<String>> containsStrings = ...
MyObject<TIntArrayList> contains_ints = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. Convert primitive arrays to their OO equivalents.