# Create a Matrix generic class with internal matrix representation using primitive types in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, generic-programming, primitive-types

I've a Matrix class that aim to encapsulate a primitive array of array. I need to use a generic version without using objects internally for memory allocation problems. Is there any way to do that in Java? I can make a series of if statements to check the type but probably there is a better way to do it.

Comment: No, it's impossible, because of the nature of generics in Java: all generics are removed after compilation so there only type Object exists in code.

Comment: @Michel_T. so the best way is to make a series of if statements?

Comment: you mean if you want to create some an array of some type? I think yes. Or use something like MatrixInt, MatrixDouble etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910584/how-can-we-work-with-generic-types-and-primitives-in-java I think this might be helpful for you

Comment: Create a generic class parametrized with a non-primitive value type (extends Number would be nice). Then use a small parser that generates for every primitive class int/double/float a separate java source like IntMatrix. Partly that was done in Java SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always wrap the array in an object that implements `List<List<Integer>>` and then treat that as a matrix.

```
private static class Matrix extends AbstractList<List<Integer>> implements List<List<Integer>> {
    final int[][] data;

    private static class Row extends AbstractList<Integer> implements List<Integer> {
        final int[] row;

        public Row(int[] row) {
            this.row = row;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return row[index];
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return row.length;
        }
    }

    public Matrix(int[][] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> get(int index) {
        return new Row(data[index]);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return data.length;
    }
}

public List<List<Integer>> asMatrix(int[][] data) {
    return new Matrix(data);
}

private void test() {
    int[][] test = new int[][] {
            {1,2,3},
            {4,5,6},
            {7,8,9}
    };
    List<List<Integer>> matrix = asMatrix(test);
    System.out.println(matrix);
}
```

This approach can be extended to allow writing back to the inner array just by implementing `set` in the inner `Row` class. Extending `Matrix` to allow a `get(row,col)` method would be trivial.

You will need to write one of these for each primitive you need to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Some existing Java linear algebra libraries have a design for this. To see how it's done in ojAlgo look at the classes in the org.ojalgo.array package:

https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo/blob/develop/src/org/ojalgo/array/Array2D.java

The actual linear algebra classes extend or delegate to the various classes in the array package.

Answer (score 0):

For speed and compactness many of us add an matrix accessor shim on top of an array of a primitive class.  For example (pseudo code)

```
  int data[WIDTH*HEIGHT]; // populate it
  int at(int x, int y) { return data[y*WIDTH+x]; }
```